# Convert php regular expression in javascript regex

Tags: regex, vba

I've been struggling all day to try and convert the following regex that works for php, into a form for javascript.
I am trying to use it for some VBA where I can replace "sedol" with a variable so I can loop through the string to get "name" and other elements
So for example below I would want the outcome to = '0452173'

php regex:

```
(?<="sedol":")(.+?)(?=",")
```

String extract:

```
"sedol":"0452173","name":"Aberdeen Japan Equity (Class I)", .....
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JS doesn't support look behind.
However, you could do this:

```
var re = new RegExp("(?:\"" + yourVar + "\":\"(.+?)(?=\",\")");
```

Then use

```
var res = re.exec(yourString);
if (res != null) { // match
    return res[1]; // the matched part of (.+?)
}
```